# Why is edit question feature unavailable?

Tags: discussion, support, editing

I wanted to edit this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225258/apt-get-install-does-not-work-gives-the-same-error-every-time-e-unable-to-loca) for giving some sanity to it, but saw that the `Edit` feature is seen disabled. Why is it so?

N.B: I can edit other questions.

**Image:** `Edit` feature is shown disabled (highlighted in red):

[image: edit button disabled]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you did read the tooltip over the disabled edit button, it would have told you there is a pending suggested edit waiting to be reviewed.

Anyway, I have reviewed the suggested edit and you should now be able to edit the question if you want to.

See also:

- [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled)

Comment: Thankyou, I hadn't notice the tooltip. :) I have seen your edit and added another edit.